# Kafka - Failed to clean up log for __consumer_offsets-10 in dir

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am seeing the following exception in one of the broker log files.
Set up : 3 brokers

I am ok to remove the files c:\tmp directory. However, little curious why this broker got into this state.

```
    log4j:ERROR Failed to rename [C:\confluent-5.5.0/logs/log-cleaner.log] to [C:\confluent-5.5.0/logs/log-cleaner.log.2020-06-18-09].     
[2020-06-18 14:10:41,361] ERROR Failed to clean up log for __consumer_offsets-10 in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs-3 due to IOException (kafka.s
erver.LogDirFailureChannel)                                                                                                            
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\tmp\kafka-logs-3\__consumer_offsets-10\00000000000000000000.timeindex.cleaned -> C:\tmp\kafka-log
s-3\__consumer_offsets-10\00000000000000000000.timeindex.swap: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another p
rocess.                                                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                       
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)                                                
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)                                                  
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:387)                                                                   
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)                                               
        at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)                                                                                   
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:834)                                                  
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.renameTo(AbstractIndex.scala:207)                                                                   
        at kafka.log.LogSegment.changeFileSuffixes(LogSegment.scala:497)                                                               
        at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$replaceSegments$4(Log.scala:2288)                                                                    
        at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$replaceSegments$4$adapted(Log.scala:2288)                                                            
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)                                                                     
        at kafka.log.Log.replaceSegments(Log.scala:2288)                                                                               
        at kafka.log.Cleaner.cleanSegments(LogCleaner.scala:605)                                                                       
        at kafka.log.Cleaner.$anonfun$doClean$6(LogCleaner.scala:530)                                                                  
        at kafka.log.Cleaner.doClean(LogCleaner.scala:529)                                                                             
        at kafka.log.Cleaner.clean(LogCleaner.scala:503)                                                                               
        at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.cleanLog(LogCleaner.scala:372)                                                           
        at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.cleanFilthiestLog(LogCleaner.scala:345)                                                  
        at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.tryCleanFilthiestLog(LogCleaner.scala:325)                                               
        at kafka.log.LogCleaner$CleanerThread.doWork(LogCleaner.scala:314)                                                             
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:96)                                                             
        Suppressed: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\tmp\kafka-logs-3\__consumer_offsets-10\00000000000000000000.timeindex.cleaned
 -> C:\tmp\kafka-logs-3\__consumer_offsets-10\00000000000000000000.timeindex.swap: The process cannot access the file because it is bei
ng used by another process.                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                       
                at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:86)                                        
                at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)                                          
                at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:301)                                                           
                at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)                                       
                at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)                                                                           
                at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:831)                                          
                ... 15 more                                                                                                            
[2020-06-18 14:10:41,441] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=3] Stopping serving replicas in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs-3 (kafka.server.ReplicaMana
ger)                                                                                                                                   
[2020-06-18 14:10:41,445] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 3] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(__consumer_offsets-22, __consumer
_offsets-4, stock-prices-2, __consumer_offsets-7, __consumer_offsets-46, stock-prices-1, __consumer_offsets-25, __consumer_offsets-49, 
__consumer_offsets-16, __consumer_offsets-28, __consumer_offsets-31, __consumer_offsets-37, stock-prices-0, __consumer_offsets-19, stoc
k_topic-0, __consumer_offsets-13, __consumer_offsets-43, __consumer_offsets-1, __consumer_offsets-34, __consumer_offsets-10, __consumer
_offsets-40) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)                                                                                      
[2020-06-18 14:10:41,448] INFO [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 3] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(__consumer_offsets-22, __con
sumer_offsets-4, stock-prices-2, __consumer_offsets-7, __consumer_offsets-46, stock-prices-1, __consumer_offsets-25, __consumer_offsets
-49, __consumer_offsets-16, __consumer_offsets-28, __consumer_offsets-31, __consumer_offsets-37, stock-prices-0, __consumer_offsets-19,
 stock_topic-0, __consumer_offsets-13, __consumer_offsets-43, __consumer_offsets-1, __consumer_offsets-34, __consumer_offsets-10, __con
sumer_offsets-40) (kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager)                                                                            
[2020-06-18 14:10:41,492] WARN [ReplicaManager broker=3] Broker 3 stopped fetcher for partitions __consumer_offsets-22,__consumer_offse
ts-4,stock-prices-2,__consumer_offsets-7,__consumer_offsets-46,stock-prices-1,__consumer_offsets-25,__consumer_offsets-49,__consumer_of
fsets-16,__consumer_offsets-28,__consumer_offsets-31,__consumer_offsets-37,stock-prices-0,__consumer_offsets-19,stock_topic-0,__consume
r_offsets-13,__consumer_offsets-43,__consumer_offsets-1,__consumer_offsets-34,__consumer_offsets-10,__consumer_offsets-40 and stopped m
oving logs for partitions  because they are in the failed log directory C:\tmp\kafka-logs-3. (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)             
[2020-06-18 14:10:41,494] WARN Stopping serving logs in dir C:\tmp\kafka-logs-3 (kafka.log.LogManager)                                 
[2020-06-18 14:10:41,576] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in C:\tmp\kafka-logs-3 have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)
```

Comment: Just try to delete C:\kafka\kafka-logs\__consumer_offsets-10 which you have. And restart services. Here is the duplicated question which helped me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54146324/kafka-broker-shutdown-while-cleaning-up-log-files